# Conditionally passing slots to child components

Tags: svelte, web-component, svelte-component

It is now possible to [pass slots to child components](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2079#issuecomment-700970527) (in Svelte 3.29.0+).

However I would like to pass the slots only if they are present, but in the example provided below, I am receiving a slot with empty body in Window component (which has been wrapped inside of another component `FancyWindow`). REPL [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/312b03b785ef4452a551959efa357def?version=3.55.1).

```html
<FancyWindow>
  <span>Fancy</span>
  <Window name={panelName}>
    <slot name="header" slot="header" />
    <slot name="options" slot="options" />
    <slot name="body" slot="body" />
  </Window>
</FancyWindow>
```

I can add a condition checking `$$slots` object for say, `options`:

```html
{#if $$slots['options']}
  <slot name="options" slot="options" />
{/if}
```

But this results in an error:

```
Element with a slot='...' attribute must be a child of a component
or a descendant of a custom element
```

Is there a way to do conditionally pass slots down to children components?

Comment: Just found that this has been raised as an issue [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6059#issuecomment-1119506120) and [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5312#issuecomment-1152961505)